# docker-compose update from S3 bucket

Tags: docker

Our Dockerfile invokes a python script which copies a binary from S3 to /usr/bin. This works fine the first time. But from then on "docker-compose build" does nothing because everything is cached. This is a problem if the binary has changed.

Short of building with --no-cache, what is the best way to make sure "docker-compose build" will always pick up the new binary if there is one. We don't mind if it unnecessarily downloads the binary even if unchanged, so long as it does work then the binary has changed.

Seems like we want a Dockerfile step that always executes?

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN apt-get -y install --reinstall ca-certificates
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    wget \
    vim \
    git \
    python3.5 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    libpcap0.8-dev

RUN ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python3

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install Python Requirements
RUN pip3 install -r etc/python/requirements.txt

# Download/Install processor and associated libs
RUN python3 setup_processor.py

RUN mkdir -p /logs

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Where setup_processor.py downloads directly from S3 to /usr/bin.

Comment: Post your Dockerfile

Comment: @TarunLalwani added dockerfile above.

Answer (score 1):

So as of now there is no direct feature like this. But there is a workaround to your solution.

Add Build argument before your download step

```
ARG BUILD_ON=now
# Download/Install processor and associated libs
RUN python3 setup_processor.py
```

While building the image use below

```
docker build --build-arg BUILD_ON=$(date) ....
```

This will always make sure that you get a change in the ARG step and all steps cache after that will be invalidated

A feature has already been requested and being worked out on below thread

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1996